# Solution for derivative example

Tags: derivatives

I trying understand derivatives and faced with this example, but my low math background don't allow me undestand all steps of this solution.
Can anyone clarify for me in details every step of this example.

$$\begin{align}
{\partial \over \partial \theta_{j}}J(\theta)&={\partial \over \partial \theta_{j}}{1\over 2}(h_{\theta}(x)-y)^{2}\\
&=2.{1\over 2}(h_{\theta}(x)-y).{\partial \over \partial \theta_{j}}(h_{\theta}
(x)-y)\\
&=(h_{\theta}(x)-y).{\partial \over \partial \theta_{j}}(\sum_{i=0}^{n}\theta_{i}x_{i}-y)\\&=(h_{\theta}(x)-y)x_{j}\end{align}$$

Comment: Any particular point you don't understand?

Comment: There are are lot of elements in that that doesn't have a mening without any context.

Comment: @Henrik: Things are pretty easy to understand from just the given elements: it seems that $\theta = (\theta_1, \dots, \theta_n)$ and $J(\theta) = \frac 1 2  (h_\theta (x) - y)^2$ with $h_\theta (x) = \sum _{i=0} ^n \theta_i x_i - y$, and $x = (x_1, \dots, x_n)$ and $y$ being constants.

Comment: @AlexM. Thanks, Alex. All right.

Comment: The notation suggests that $\theta$ must be a vector or tuple of parameters, in order for those partial derivatives to make sense.  But we lack a definition of $J(\theta)$ necessary to proceed in taking these partial derivatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am giving you an example to explain few basics.

Let y = $(2x + 1)^3$

Then differentiate with respect to x.

First we have to differentiate the power then term.

So we have,

$\frac{dy}{dx} = 3(2x+1)^{3-1} \cdot \frac{d}{dx}(2x + 1)$

$\frac{dy}{dx} = 3(2x+1)^2 \cdot (2.1.x^{1-1} + 0)$

As differentiation of constant term is zero.

So we have,

$\frac{dy}{dx} = 3(2x+1)^2 \cdot 2 $

> Edit -

[Here are some formula you can see and learn.](http://www.pleacher.com/mp/mlessons/calculus/deriv2.html)

Comment: Can you clarify, why multiplier 3 appear in first term and why we decrease a degree 3 by one?

Comment: I provided a link. See 4th formula.

Comment: In place of x any term is used.

Comment: I understand what in practice we need use list of formulas like this, for resolving any derivative expression? Right?

Comment: Formula are only one part. Practice is important thing. You can start with easy questions and after sometime you can do any question.

Comment: In your question in first step derivative for power  2 comes forward and power of function becomes 1. Then now we have to differentiate term.

Comment: In third term h(x) replaced by value. Then in next step its derivative.

Comment: Great thanks! You really helped me undestand question better.

Comment: Derivative of y w.r.t theta is 0.

Comment: Your welcome. From the next time please add what you tried. So that no one can down vote your question. I upvoted your question because you are new here and your question not enough bad.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the chain rule? Look that up. And apply it to your Q. What part are you actually stuck on? What subject is it for? Regression analysis? What do the terms mean?

Comment: Right, it's from regression analysis. J is a cost function, theta - parameter

Comment: Okay, well apply the chain rule as mentioned above. Substitute in $x-j$. Which is what by the way?

Comment: Edit: $x_j$ term

Comment: I don't know chain rule. Thanks for this rule, I need learn it before I will can understand your advices.